# True or False Statements JQuery Working Different in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Live Link : http://velnikolic.com/elliotDev5/

```js
contentActive = true;
var selector = '.mainNav li';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
  $(selector).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});    
            
$(".filter").click(function() {
  category = $(this).data("filter");

  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }

  pLoaded();
           
  if (contentActive == true && status == "false") {
    $('.contentWrap').children().fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function() {
      $('#portfolio').mixItUp({
        load: {
          filter: category
        }
      });
      contentActive = false;
    });
  } else {
    $('#portfolio').mixItUp({
      load: {
        filter: category
      }
    });
  }
         
}); 

$('.link a').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  
  $('.contentWrap').children().fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function() {
    pLoaded();
    alert(status);
    
    if(status == "true") {
      $('#portfolio').fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function() {
        $('#portfolio').mixItUp('destroy', true);
        $('#portfolio').removeAttr('style');

        $(id).fadeIn('slow', function () {
          // Animation complete
        });
      });                        
    } else {
      $(id).fadeIn('slow', function () {
        // Animation complete
      });
    }
                    
    contentActive = true;
  });
});

var status;
status = false;

function pLoaded() {
  status = $('#portfolio').mixItUp('isLoaded');
  return status;
}

$(".nav li a").click(function(){
  if ($( "#navMenu" ).hasClass( "canvas-slid" )) { 
    $('#navMenu').offcanvas('hide');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 offcanvas-xs" id="navMenu">
  <div class="sidebar-nav">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav mainNav">
        <img id="logo" class="img-responsive hidden-xs" src="assets/img/logo2.jpg" />
        <li class="link">
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link">
          <a href="#aboutSection">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-1">
          <a href="#">Animation</a>
        </li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-2">
          <a href="#">Commercial</a>
        </li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-3"><a href="#">Documentary</a>
        </li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-4">
          <a href="#">Film</a>
        </li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-5">
          <a href="#">Music</a>
        </li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-6">
          <a href="#">Video Games</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link">
          <a href="#services">Services</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="contentWrap">
  //content
</div>

<div id="portfolio">

</div>
```

Basically when you click a non filter link it check if theres the portfolio div and fade it out if there is, then load the content.

If a filter is clicked it should check if there is any other content fade it out if so and load the portfolio.

The problem seems to be with the if statements, different iterations work in firefox and chrome and different iterations work only in IE. Driving me crazy to figure out one that works for both

Comment: care to give some more information about which statements work in which way in which browser - and why bother with a code snippet that doesn't run, just post a code block instead

Comment: The above is working in latest version of Chrome and Firefox not IE11

Comment: not the code snippet ... click in anything and get a `$(...).mixItUp is not a function` error ... so ... yeah

Comment: So, you say you can make it work in IE using a different iteration of the if statements ... can you show code that does work in IE **as well** as the code that doesn't - then we can see the difference

Comment: Added live link. Looking through different versions now to find IE version. Didn't keep very organized.

Comment: You have ' status == "false" ' - is this correct? Should status be a string or a boolean?

Comment: if(status == "true") {
      $('#portfolio').fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function() {
        $('#portfolio').mixItUp('destroy', true);
        $('#portfolio').removeAttr('style');

        $(id).fadeIn('slow', function () {
          // Animation complete
        });
      });                        
    } else {
      $(id).fadeIn('slow', function () {
        // Animation complete
      });
    }

Comment: The above part does not work in IE... skips directly the the else statement even though the debugger saids "true"

Comment: and it is supposed to be a boolean, both ways work identically though. W

Comment: Ok removing the quots from "true" and "false" makes it not work in chrome and firefox

Comment: Looks like  status = $('#portfolio').mixItUp('isLoaded'); returns as a string in IE11 and a boolean in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, mixitup2's callback `.mixItUp('isLoaded');` returns as a string in IE 11 and a boolean in Chrome and Firefox. My solution could probably be more elegant, but this is what I'm using for not.

```js
if ( (contentActive == true) && (status == "false" || status == false ))
```